# what is timeout state in monit and how to get out of it?

Tags: monit

Could someone explain what exactly timeout status means in monit, how is it useful and how would the process get out of that state once it gets in it? I read the documentation and it didnt exactly elaborate much on this

Comment: Do you have a http check in your conf? Does your application respond to http?

Answer (score 0):

I think after a service times out, then it becomes unmonitored (with the intent that it needs manual intervention to be restarted and have monitoring enabled).

So, if you have "if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout", then after 5 restarts the service will become unmonitored.